# Play working offline

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to start my play application offline. I got only access by ssh via local network and server is behind firewall. I've tried to set offline := true in plugins.sbt but it didn't helped. Play is still trying to connnect with remote repos:

```
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.10.2/ivys/ivy.xml
```

I know, that "Connection timed out" is firewall issue, but I can't change settings...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `play dist` command to prepare standalone version of your application and then use it on the offline server. It will fetch all required dependencies, so won't require connection to external repos anymore.

More details at [Play's docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/ProductionDist)