# Run play without network connection

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

How can I develop a Play Framework application without a network connection? Every time I run `play` it tries to connect to some repository to download things:

```
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\Vincent\Documents\GitHub\TestApplication\play\project
[error] Server access Error: Connection reset url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/commons-io/commons-io/2.0.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection reset url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/commons-io/commons-io/2.0.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection reset url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.6.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection reset url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.6.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection reset url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.apache.commons/commons-compress/1.4.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection reset url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.apache.commons/commons-compress/1.4.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection reset url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.tukaani/xz/1.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection reset url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.tukaani/xz/1.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection reset url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.specs2/specs2_2.10/2.1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection reset url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.specs2/specs2_2.10/2.1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection reset url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scalaz/scalaz-concurrent_2.10/7.0.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection reset url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scalaz/scalaz-concurrent_2.10/7.0.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection reset url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.2.5/jars/sbt-plugin.jar
[error] Server access Error: Connection reset url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.2.5/jars/sbt-plugin.jar
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? Y
```

These are the contents of my sbt files:

**plugins.sbt**

```scala
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.0")
```

**build.sbt**

```scala
name := "TestApplication"

version := "{VERSION}"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache
)     

play.Project.playJavaSettings
```

The answer in [Play working offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237501/play-working-offline) only talks about deploying/distributing a Play application, not developing.

Answer (score 1):

You can **try** setting `offline := true` in your build.sbt. Most of the time it works.

Comment: Tried that already, didn't appear to make a difference with anything unfortunately.

Comment: You need to resolve/download once, then put it in offline mode. Otherwise you have to setup a local Maven/sbt repo.

Comment: The files that are being searched for appear to be the same as the ones in `C:\Play\repository\local`, is there any way to indicate to Play to look there instead?